# copying part of a list to a vector in C++

Tags: c++, std

Im getting back into c++ after a decade away from it.

Im trying to get the last 5 items of a list and sort them.  Here is the code I have so far.

```
int myints[] = {32,55,34,22,33,55,22};
std::list<int> mylist(myints, myints+7);
std::vector<int> myvector2(mylist.end() - 5, mylist.end());
std::sort(myvector2.begin(), myvector2.end());
```

However I am getting the following error.

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('iterator' (aka '__list_iterator<int, void *>') and 'int')
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Try `std::advance(mylist.end(), -5)`. List iterators are not random access.

Comment: The [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) iterator is a [*bidirectional iterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), and you can't subtract values from those.

Comment: Side note: for initialization of mylist you can also take `mylist(begin(myints), end(myints))`. No need to hard code the array length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code shows the age of your knowledge. Since C++ 11, you've been able to initialize containers more directly:

```
std::list<int> mylist{32,55,34,22,33,55,22};
```

For the question you're actually asking, I'd use `prev`:

```
std::vector<int> myvector2(std::prev(mylist.end(), 5), mylist.end());
```

You can also use `std::advance`, but it doesn't return the value it produces, so it's often somewhat clumsy to use:

```
auto pos = mylist.end();
std::advance(pos, -5);
std::vector<int> myvector2(pos, mylist.end());
```

As a final note, I'd advise that almost *any* use of `std::list` should be treated as "guilty until proven innocent". It's *rarely* useful--even in cases that are devised specifically to highlight its (supposed) advantages, `std:vector` frequently ends up faster.

Comment: Is that first line right? do i need to use parenthesis.  Either way your solution for my problem worked.  thanks.

Comment: @TommieJones: No, parentheses aren't necessary (at least with a current compiler).